CSS Flexbox and gap properties
\<div class="container-7"\>

\<div class=" box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\<div class="box box1"\>\</div\>

\</div\>

.container-7 {

display: flex;

flex-direction: column;

column-gap: 24px;

}

box  {

height: 100px;

flex-basis: calc(25% - 24px);

flex-grow: 1;

flex-shrink: 1

background-color: orchid;

}

I have seven containers. After giving flex basis: calc (25% - 24px), i have first four containers in the first row and the next three.  I want the next three in the second row but in the centre of the row. How can i achieve this?

Remove flex-direction: column;. Surely this should be flex-direction: row;. Allow wrapping then center with justify-content.


.container-7 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  gap: 24px;
}

.box {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  flex: calc(25% - 24px) 0 0;
  background-color: orchid;
}
<div class="container-7">

  <div class=" box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>

  <div class="box box1"></div>
</div>



